# date range validation by month in nodejs moment.js

Tags: node.js, date, validation, momentjs

I am trying to validate or check the date range by passing month and year, If date range come under the given month range between, then it would be valid else error.

```
month = "04, 06, 2022"; // from-month, to-month, year

date = "12-05-2022" // DD-MM-YYYY
```

```
from month = 04
to month = 06
year = 2022
```

I read the documentation but didn't achive the goal.
I want if I am passing this data below -

```
month = "04, 06, 2022"; // from-month, to-month, year
date = "12-07-2022" // DD-MM-YYYY => error
date = "12-05-2022" // DD-MM-YYYY => success
```

```
let value = '12-05-2022'; //DD-MM-YYYY
let check = moment(value,'DD-MM-YYYY', true).isValid();
console.log(check) //returns true
return check
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a `range` to check if the date corresponding to `value` is contained:

```
const year = 2022;
const fromMonth = 4;
const toMonth = 6;

const startDate = new Date(year, fromMonth, 12);
const endDate = new Date(year, toMonth, 15);

const value = '12-05-2022';
const check = moment().range(startDate, endDate).contains(new Date(value));

console.log(check);
```

Comment: how `12, 15`  line no. `4 and 5` comes `new Date(year, fromMonth, 12)` and `new Date(year, toMonth, 15)`

Comment: @DanjayRathor You should choose those values depending on the days you want to filter